# watch specific property of different object keys

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have this object

```
vm.obj = {
    prop1: 1,
    prop2: 'test2',
    prop3: ['test 3'],
    hashes: {
        objToWatchOnePlusHash123: {
            watchThis: 'value 1',
            subOne: 1,
            subTwo: '2',
        },
        objToWatchTwoPlusHash456: {
            watchThis: 'value 2',
            subOne: 3,
            subTwo: '4',
        },
    },
};
```

And I only want to watch the value of `watchThis` in each `objToWatch*PlusHash*` (this will be an actual hash so it's gonna be unique).

Currently, I run with

```
$scope.$watch('vm.obj.hashes', function (newVal, oldVal) {
    /* */
}, true)
```

But it also gets triggered by changes to `subOne` and `subTwo` in each object.

Possible to only watch what I want to watch? Considering that they are two objects with different keys.

Comment: With this structure JSON. It is not possible to do. as each object has a different key. you should watch the whole key. No way else I guess.

Comment: Hmm. Yeah. I guess it won't really be possible.

Answer (score 0):

In this JSON

```
vm.obj = {
    prop1: 1,
    prop2: 'test2',
    prop3: ['test 3'],
    hashes: {
        objToWatchOnePlusHash123: {
            watchThis: 'value 1',
            subOne: 1,
            subTwo: '2',
        },
        objToWatchTwoPlusHash456: {
            watchThis: 'value 2',
            subOne: 3,
            subTwo: '4',
        },
    },
};
```

It is not possible to watch `watchThis` in all objects without knowing the `objToWatch***` property. You can watch the whole object only.

One thing you can do is If you can able to get the hash key at the time. (possible workaround)

Then

```
$scope.$watch('vm.obj.hashes', function (newVal, oldVal) {
    if(newVal[hash].watchThis !== oldVal[hash].watchThis){
    // do something
     }
}, true)
```

Comment: Yep. This is the only way possible.

Comment: upvote this answer if you find this helpful and accept the answer to close this question. @iamdevlinph

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can *watch specific property of different object keys*. For this write 
*watch* function, which will return `value` - some kind of composition of all watched properties, at this particular case, it is JSON representation of object with corresponding properties:

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  var vm = this;
  
  vm.obj = {
    prop1: 1,
    prop2: 'test2',
    prop3: ['test 3'],
    hashes: {
        objToWatchOnePlusHash123: {
            watchThis: 'value 1',
            subOne: 1,
            subTwo: '2',
        },
        objToWatchTwoPlusHash456: {
            watchThis: 'value 2',
            subOne: 3,
            subTwo: '4',
        },
      },
  };
  
  $scope.$watch(function(){
    var value = {};
    for(var prop in vm.obj.hashes)
      if(prop.match(/^objToWatch\D+PlusHash\d+$/))
        value[prop] = vm.obj.hashes[prop].watchThis;      
    return JSON.stringify(value);
  }, function(newVal, oldVal){    
      console.log('OldVal:' + oldVal + '\n\rNewVal:' + newVal);
  })  
}])
```

```html
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app='app' ng-controller="ctrl as vm">
  <div ng-repeat='(key, val) in vm.obj.hashes'>
    {{key}}.watchThis: <input type='text' ng-model='vm.obj.hashes[key].watchThis'>
  </div>   
  objToWatchTwoPlusHash456.subOne: <input type='text' ng-model='vm.obj.hashes.objToWatchTwoPlusHash456.subOne'>
</div>
```